# Concatenating C++ source files using the preprocessor without standard library includes

Tags: c++, gcc, c-preprocessor

I have a `C++` project and I want to merge all source files into a single `main.cpp` file. It seems like the preprocessor is a good fit for this task, hence I ran the following command:

```
g++ -E main.cpp > main.i
```

This generated a huge preprocessed source file including ugly compiler toolchain library includes. Is there a way to just concatenate project input source files without uncommenting all angle bracket includes like `#include <iostream>`?

Comment: With `all source files` you assume all headers linked to a cpp or also multiple cpp files?

Comment: @JVApen: The entire project linked together which includes `*.h` headers and `*.cpp` source files.

Comment: "The entire project"? How is it to know which files belong to the project?

Comment: @Beta: According to the includes in the `main.cpp`. The preprocessor is able to resolve all headers with the command given in the question but all `*.cpp` files have to be specified manually.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? It's against common sense.

Comment: @Zereges: It is easier to apply an analysis or transformations on the source code if everything is in a single file.

Comment: The `#include` statements in `main` usually refer to header files (`foo.h`), not source files (`bar.cpp`). First, those two sets of files do not generally line up on-to-one. Second, concatenating the source files might not produce a compilable file. This whole approach seems wrong.

Comment: Using an alternate path where all system files are empty might almost works. If you don't include the real content, then some macros might not be replaced. So you would have to evaluate yourself if that approach could works… However as others have said, the idea is suspicious. In real life, you usually want to split files more.

Comment: Well, it works besides duplicate definitions which have to be eliminated as well. But maybe there is an easier way to do the merge.

Comment: What about `static` variables, by the way? They could collide if you merge two compilation units.

Comment: "_maybe there is an easier way to do the merge_" - I'd ask myself if there's an easier way to solve the real problem instead."_It is easier to apply an analysis or transformations on the source code if everything is in a single file_" - What kind of analysis and transformations become easier? Perheps there are better tools available?

Comment: @BullyWiiPlaza [nuklear](https://github.com/vurtun/nuklear/tree/master/src) is given as a single-file header for C projects which by using a build.py and paq.sh in its code brings all the files of the project together. It may be similar to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

On POSIX systems, you can use the shell program `cat` to con*cat*enate files:

```
 cat list.cpp of.cpp files.cpp | g++ -xc++ -
```

Comment: It seems like a simple `cat` would be erroneous for concatenating source code files...

Comment: @BullyWiiPlaza in what way?

Comment: It will not follow the include order. Also your command does not yield a proper output of the concatenated result. It prints something like `<stdin>:13:2: error: stray '#' in program
<stdin>:13:3: error: 'include' does not name a type`